# How to download a file via the browser from Amazon S3 using Python (and boto) at Google App Engine?

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, amazon-s3, boto

I have a python script running inside the Google App Engine with boto 1.9b that gets all keys inside a S3-Bucket. The output is formated as a HTML-Table.

```
bucket_instance = conn_s3.get_bucket(bucketname)
liste_keys = bucket_instance.get_all_keys()

table = '<table>'
for i in range(laenge_liste_keys):
  table = table + '<tr><td>'+str(liste_keys[i].name)+</td></tr>'
table = '</table>'
```

How can I realize the key-names as links that enable the user to download the key via the browser?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is found.

```
generate_url(expires_in, method='GET', headers=None, query_auth=True, force_http=False)
```

This makes it easy to create a link for every key which is valid for x seconds.

Answer (score 2):

The public URL for the file would be something like:

```
http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket_name/key_name
```

So in your code, add links with their href attributes pointing to that URL.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think, this works only with keys that have the ACL public-read.

Comment: Correct. You can't read files that don't have public read access over the internet.